# Use trigger on DELETE to retrieve original SQL command and user who did it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, trigger, delete, audit

I'm trying to create an audit log to store all delete commands on some tables, on MSSQL 2012.

What I need is the username that executed it and the command executed, then I can insert them on a log table.

I'm finding many example for creating trigger, but none that shows how to retrieve these info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the username, there are a bunch of built-in functions that will return the current user name. They are not all the same, so [take your pick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/security-functions-transact-sql) - I typically use [`SUSER_SNAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-sname-transact-sql).

For the command, if you were on a supported and non-antique version (even SQL Server 2014 would do), you could use [`sys.dm_exec_input_buffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-input-buffer-transact-sql) to tell you the last batch sent by the current user (identified by [`@@SPID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/spid-transact-sql)), so in the body of your trigger you could have:

```
INSERT dbo.LoggingTable(username, command<, other cols>)
SELECT SUSER_SNAME(), event_info<, other data>
  FROM sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(@@SPID, NULL);
```

On SQL Server 2012, it's going to be a lot uglier. You'll need a #temp table to hold the output of dynamic SQL executing [`DBCC INPUTBUFFER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-inputbuffer-transact-sql):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@me) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;';

CREATE TABLE #dbcc
(
  EventType  nvarchar(128),
  Parameters int,
  EventInfo  nvarchar(max),
  UserName   nvarchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT SUSER_SNAME()
);

INSERT #dbcc(EventType, Parameters, EventInfo)
  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@me int', @@SPID;

INSERT dbo.LoggingTable(username, command<, other cols>)
SELECT UserName, EventInfo<, other data>
  FROM #dbcc;
```

Comment: tnx a lot! I'm gonna try it tomorrow at work, I hope it works and the DBCC doesn't affect performance.